# Qt QTableView context menu and right selection

Tags: qt, delegates, contextmenu, qtableview, qmenu

Hello I'm using a `QTableView` with custom item delegate.

I'm using `editorEvent` in the delegate to show a context menu which is different for each item that is right-clicked.
The menu is displayed using `QMenu::exec()`.

The problem is that when i right click on a non-selected cell, the menu is displayed (blocking) and only after the menu disappears the cell is selected.
This is because mouse click is captured first by the delegate, and then propagated to the view to make the selection.

Which alternative/workaround might I try?

- `QMenu::popup()` does not work in my case, i think because the click propagation closes the menu;
- Handling selection in the delegate?
- Moving the context menu code out of the delegate to a custom control class?
- ...

**EDIT**

I did catch `QEvent::MouseButtonPress`. Using `MouseButtonRelease` instead makes the cell be selected first and then the context appears, but if you move the mouse while having button pressed the selection remains where you pressed the button while the context menu appears for the cell where the button was released.

I think that the only way to fix this is moving this code out of the delegate as suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to show the menu when the user makes a right click then there's no need to create a custom item delegate.

You can handle the `mouseReleaseEvent` when `event->button() == Qt::RightButton` and get the selected item using `QTableView::selectionModel()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need the delegate for custom editing purposes, so I thought to put context menu there to have all in the same place.
Actually I think your suggestion is the best way. I'll modifiy my code soon and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by cdonts using the delegate to show a context menu is not only not needed, but also not well performing.

What I have used is `QWidget::setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu)` and the signal `QWidget::customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)`. This allows me to check actual selection asking the view its SelectionModel before creating the context menu (which could be done in the model to easily customize the menu and edit the data accordingly).

Remember to use `QTableView->viewport()->maptoglobalpos(point)` to obtain global coordinates at which the menu should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Worked like @alez suggested. To get the coordinates I used `QTableView->mapToGlobal(pos)`